# Keras : KeyError: 'acc' , during plotting

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, keras

i'm trying to visualize the Training plot of my Model , and i get this Error :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "train.py", line 120, in <module>
    plt.plot(H.history['acc'])
    KeyError: 'acc'
```

& here's the Full Code :

```
     # set the matplotlib backend so figures can be saved in the background
     import matplotlib
     matplotlib.use("Agg")

     # import the necessary packages
     from pyimagesearch.resnet import ResNet
     from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
     from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
     from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
     from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
     from keras.optimizers import SGD
     from keras.utils import np_utils
     from imutils import paths
     import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     import numpy as np
     import argparse
     import cv2
     import os

     # construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
     ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
     ap.add_argument("-d", "--dataset", required=True,
         help="path to input dataset")
     ap.add_argument("-a", "--augment", type=int, default=-1,
         help="whether or not 'on the fly' data augmentation should be used")
     ap.add_argument("-p", "--plot", type=str, default="plot.png",
         help="path to output loss/accuracy plot")
     args = vars(ap.parse_args())

     # initialize the initial learning rate, batch size, and number of
     # epochs to train for
     INIT_LR = 1e-1
     BS = 8
     EPOCHS = 50

     # grab the list of images in our dataset directory, then initialize
     # the list of data (i.e., images) and class images
     print("[INFO] loading images...")
     imagePaths = list(paths.list_images(args["dataset"]))
     data = []
     labels = []

     # loop over the image paths
     for imagePath in imagePaths:
             # extract the class label from the filename, load the image, and
             # resize it to be a fixed 64x64 pixels, ignoring aspect ratio
             label = imagePath.split(os.path.sep)[-2]
             image = cv2.imread(imagePath)
             image = cv2.resize(image, (64, 64))

             # update the data and labels lists, respectively
             data.append(image)
             labels.append(label)

     # convert the data into a NumPy array, then preprocess it by scaling
     # all pixel intensities to the range [0, 1]
     data = np.array(data, dtype="float") / 255.0

     # encode the labels (which are currently strings) as integers and then
     # one-hot encode them
     le = LabelEncoder()
     labels = le.fit_transform(labels)
     labels = np_utils.to_categorical(labels, 3)

     # partition the data into training and testing splits using 75% of
     # the data for training and the remaining 25% for testing
     (trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(data, labels,
             test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

     # initialize an our data augmenter as an "empty" image data generator
     aug = ImageDataGenerator()

     # check to see if we are applying "on the fly" data augmentation, and
     # if so, re-instantiate the object
     if args["augment"] > 0:
            print("[INFO] performing 'on the fly' data augmentation")
            aug = ImageDataGenerator(
                    rotation_range=20,
                    zoom_range=0.15,
                    width_shift_range=0.2,
                    height_shift_range=0.2,
                    shear_range=0.15,
                    horizontal_flip=True,
                    fill_mode="nearest")

    # initialize the optimizer and model
    print("[INFO] compiling model...")
    opt = SGD(lr=INIT_LR, momentum=0.9, decay=INIT_LR / EPOCHS)
    model = ResNet.build(64, 64, 3, 2, (2, 3, 4),
            (32, 64, 128, 256), reg=0.0001)
    model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt,
            metrics=["accuracy"])

    # train the network
    print("[INFO] training network for {} epochs...".format(EPOCHS))
    H = model.fit_generator(
            aug.flow(trainX, trainY, batch_size=BS),
            validation_data=(testX, testY),
            steps_per_epoch=len(trainX) // BS,
            epochs=EPOCHS)

    # evaluate the network
    print("[INFO] evaluating network...")
    predictions = model.predict(testX, batch_size=BS)
    print(classification_report(testY.argmax(axis=1),
            predictions.argmax(axis=1), target_names=le.classes_))

    # plot the training loss and accuracy
    N = np.arange(0, EPOCHS)
    plt.style.use("ggplot")
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(N, H.history["loss"], label="train_loss")
    plt.plot(N, H.history['val_loss'], label="val_loss")
    plt.plot(N, H.history['acc'], label="accuracy")
    plt.plot(N, H.history['val_acc'], label="val_acc")
    plt.title("Training Loss and Accuracy on Dataset")
    plt.xlabel("Epoch #")
    plt.ylabel("Loss/Accuracy")
    plt.legend(loc="lower left")
    plt.savefig(args["plot"])
```

So, this code , is originally from the blog Pyimagesearch , on data augmentation , so , i decided to give it a try , the original "pipeline" was meant for a binary classification , so , since i was intrested in a mutli-class "task" , i brought some changes.

but the plotting part of the code , seems correct to me , i cheked on multiple posts here on Stack , checked the keras documentation , and nothing , i do not understand , why it dose not work !!!!
any suggestion would be much appreciated .
thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have you tried `H.history['accuracy']`? Since you compiled using `'accuracy'` it will probably have the same string.

Now you can always inspect what you've got:

```
for key in H.history.keys():
    print(key)
```

You will see what is logged there